# Is it possible in gh-pages Jekyll to have {{content}} expand without evaluating liquid tags?

Tags: jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I'm trying to use GitHub Pages for my project's documentation, but it includes generated html files that turn out to have illegal liquid tags.  I don't need any expansion beyond the _layout itself, but as far as I can tell, any `{% ... %}` tags in the articles' content themselves are also evaluated and there seems to be no way to suppress this, other than adding `{% raw %}...{% endraw %}` around the entire contents of every single article.

Is there any way to do this at the call site?  Something along the lines of `{{ content | unrendered }}` would be excellent.

*Note: this seems to be the opposite problem to many others, who are using `page.content` in a pre-render context and wanting it to be rendered; I've tried `page.content` but as far as I can tell it's exactly the same in my case, so no dice.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`page.content` was raw in the jekyll 2.x era. Now its rendered content.

You can use a [hook plugin](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#hooks) to add a `page.raw` field on any page.

```
Jekyll::Hooks.register :pages, :pre_render do |document|
  document.data['raw'] = document.content
end
```

If you want to do the same on posts and collections items, use a documents hook :

```
Jekyll::Hooks.register :documents, :pre_render do |document|
```

Note :

- In `:pre_render` hooks `document.content` contains raw content
- In `:post_render` hooks `document.content` contains rendered content

Comment: Looks like this would work, except that GitHub pages don't support plugins.  Fortunately, it looks like I don't actually have any content that could be confused for liquid tags, so hopefully it won't make a difference.